# Play framework form parameter

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'd first like to say that I'm completely new to play framework, i got this code from a youtube tutorial by 'whereIsMyDipp' and it's not working, i've looked at the docs and other tutorials and can't figure this one out. the play version that i'm using is 2.3.6
I'm trying to create a basic contacts form using the @helper stuff and i'm getting this error:
link to screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrCJ5.jpg

```
not found: value contactForm
```

here is my view:

```
@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._
@(contactForm: Form[Contact])
@main("wat"){
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.contactSubmit()) {
@helper.inputText(contactForm("fName"))
@helper.inputText(contactForm("lName"))
@helper.inputText(contactForm("phone"))
@helper.inputText(contactForm("email"))
@helper.inputText(contactForm("subject"))
@helper.inputText(contactForm("message"))

}
    }
```

and here are the relevant Action methods and model:

```
public class Contact {
String fName;
String lName;
String phone;
String email;
String subject;
String message;}

 final static Form<Contact> contactForm = form(Contact.class);

 public static Result ContactUs() {
    return ok(ContactUs.render(contactForm));
}

 public static Result contactSubmit() {
 Form<Contact> filledForm = form(Contact.class).bindFromRequest();
 Contact created = filledForm.get();
 return ok(submit.render(created));}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters must be declared on the first line of the template file, So this `@(contactForm: Form[Contact])` should come on the top of all..

Comment: Yeah i had it this way before and got the same error, moving it to the third line was an act of desperation.